# How to shrink rdlc report on runtime?

Tags: asp.net, reporting, rdlc, textbox

I have an rdlc report. I have some text boxes over it. I hide and show them based on specific values. But the problem is, when a text box disappears, there comes blank space in report that looks so weired. Please suggest that is there any way that I hide the text box and the other text box come in its place and there will be no blank spaces occur in my report?

Please helpppppppp ASAP ....

Answer (score 0):

Usually you just overlap the textboxes in the designer, then either will display in the correct place regardless of whether you've shown / hidden.